# Whatsapp message previews are not showing in Status bar when new message is received

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, notification-bar, nexus-5, push-notifications

I am using a Nexus 5 running the latest version of Kitkat.

Whenever I receive a new whatsapp message the status bar slightly floats up and and shows the whatsapp icon saying the message receieved from (sender's name). However after a few seconds it returns to the normal status bar with just the icon remaining, it does not show me a message preview of the content.

After I pull-down to the  notification center I can see the message preview just fine, I am having an issue with the toast notification of the status bar.

Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you talking about the same thing that happens for any notification (SMS, email, etc) the statusbar changes to a one-line preview of the notification for a couple of seconds and then changes back to normal?

Comment: Yes, it is working fine for sms, email etc. I'm only facing this problem with Whatsapp.

Comment: i receive default notification tone but nothing displayed in motification bar also it doesnt vibrate.. problems facing with whatsapp only